# How to pass select options as elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Trying to pass options thru my results.js with an error in my entries.map. I'm having a problem checking to see if array exists and has methods. I believe the error is in my data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-thunder-s7nen?file=/src/Step1.js

Step1.js
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";

```
<Controller
          name="Genre"
          // ref={register}
          control={control}
          options={[
            { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
            { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
            { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
            { value: "alternative", label: "•   Alternative" },
            { value: "anime", label: "• Anime" },
            { value: "blues", label: "• Blues" },
            
          ]}
          as={Select}
        />
```

Result.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Confetti from "react-confetti";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useData } from "./DataContext";
import { MainContainer } from "./components/MainContainer";
import { PrimaryButton } from "./components/PrimaryButton";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InsertDriveFile from "@material-ui/icons/InsertDriveFile";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    marginBottom: "30px",
  },
  table: {
    marginBottom: "30px",
  },
});

export const Result = () => {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const styles = useStyles();
  const { data } = useData();

  const entries = Object.entries(data).filter((entry) => entry[0] !== "files");
  const { files } = data;

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (data.files) {
      data.files.forEach((file) => {
        formData.append("files", file, file.name);
      });
    }

    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      formData.append(entry[0], entry[1]);
    });

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      Swal.fire("Great job!", "You've passed the challenge!", "success");
      setSuccess(true);
    }
  };

  // if (success) {
  //   return <Confetti />;
  // }

  return (
    <>
      <MainContainer>
        <Typography component="h2" variant="h5">
           Form Values
        </Typography>
        <TableContainer className={styles.root} component={Paper}>
          <Table className={styles.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Field</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Value</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {entries.map((entry) => (
                <TableRow key={entry[0]}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {entry[0]}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{entry[1].toString()}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        {files && (
          <>
            <Typography component="h2" variant="h5">
               Files
            </Typography>
            <List>
              {files.map((f, index) => (
                <ListItem key={index}>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <InsertDriveFile />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={f.name} secondary={f.size} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </>
        )}
        <PrimaryButton onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</PrimaryButton>
        <Link to="/">Start over</Link>
      </MainContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Code in sandbox appears to run and I see no errors. What is the issue?

Comment: I recieve an error of "Cannot read property 'toString' of null".                             <TableCell align="right">{entry[1].toString()}</TableCell> . i also have an error for                {entries.map((entry) => (
                <TableRow key={entry[0]}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {entry[0]}

Comment: I still see no errors in your codesandbox. Do you have a set of reproductions steps to trigger the error? In other words, please be specific/explicit in what you are doing that causes the error.

Comment: I added info into all the fields for each step whisch is Step1 to Step2 to Step3 and when I get the results back i get an error in results my entry[1] after I added the options to my code. I received this error when I added my select options as a controller on my Step1 page. When i change the the entry to "0" {entry[1].toString()} I receive a return of name and not my entry input.